# Accessing getState() in a non-Action file nor Component

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

Is there any way I can access getState() from a non-React Component nor an Action file?

I have a Util file that needs to be able to call getState() (or just any way to get the most updated state).  Usually I just pass in part of the state that I need for the function, but I have one particular function that loops and needs to get the latest function every time it does loop.

I was reading more into connect() but it seems like it only works for Components.  I was looking into Middleware, but it seems like that only interacts with executing Actions and I'm just at a road block where I don't know how to move forward.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might consider leveraging the `subscribe(listener)` method in the Redux Store.

The `subscribe` method allows you to attach a callback that is called every time the state tree may have potentially changed. This would let you call `getState()` inside the listener to get the current state tree.

The `subscribe` method is a low level API and is a bit clunky. [The documentation for Redux](http://redux.js.org/docs/api/Store.html#subscribe) also provides some linking to examples leveraging the `Observable` property of the Redux store so you can do something a bit more abstracted.

Comment: it seems like I can only use subscribe(listener) in only component files, am i wrong?

Comment: @user1189352 If I understand the documentation, you would have to call `subscribe` from within your application (a component), but the `listener` could be any function you want to pass state to.